# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'datetime.time'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime


df = pd.read_excel('c:/users/user/documents/finance deck coils data.xlsx')
df = df[['Coil Number','Amnt Left'] ]


df2 = pd.read_excel('c:/users/user/documents/Deck Coils Data.xlsx')
df3 = pd.merge(df, df2, how='right', on='Coil Number')

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('c:/users/user/documents/test.xlsx')
df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Original', index=False)
df3.loc[df3['Recieved Date'].isnull()].to_excel(writer, sheet_name= 'Zero Fifo', index=False)
df3.loc[(datetime.datetime.now() - df3['Recieved Date']) <= datetime.timedelta(180)].to_excel(writer, sheet_name= 'Under 6 Months', index=False)
df3.loc[((datetime.datetime.now() - df3['Recieved Date']) >= datetime.timedelta(181)) & ((datetime.datetime.now() - df3['Recieved Date']) <= datetime.timedelta(365))].to_excel(writer, sheet_name= '6 to 12 Months', index=False)
df3.loc[((datetime.datetime.now() - df3['Recieved Date']) >= datetime.timedelta(366)) & ((datetime.datetime.now() - df3['Recieved Date']) <= datetime.timedelta(730))].to_excel(writer, sheet_name= '12 to 24 Months', index=False)
df3.loc[(datetime.datetime.now() - df3['Recieved Date']) >= datetime.timedelta(731)].to_excel(writer, sheet_name= 'Over 24 Months', index=False)
writer.save()
```

I am getting an error on this line:

```
df3.loc[(datetime.datetime.now() - df3['Recieved Date']) <= datetime.timedelta(180)].to_excel(writer, sheet_name= 'Under 6 Months', index=False)
```

df3['Recieved Date'] data type is object. I do not know if I need to convert it to date time. How would I do that? The date format is as follows:

2017-06-22 00:00:00

Answer (score 0):

I would use the parsing tool in the datetime module to convert the entire column "Received Date" to a datetime object. Assuming that the time is as a 12-hour clock, for your given date format it would look something like this:

```
def parse_datetime(date_to_convert):
    pattern = "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S"
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(date_to_convert,pattern)
```

Then you can apply it to the dataframe like this:

```
df3['Received Date'] = df3['Received Date'].apply(lambda row: parse_datetime(row))
```

You can also add error handling within the function if there are values that you don't want parsed.

Comment: I got the following error: TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.datetime

Comment: Ok, so two things could be going on. 1) The entire column is already formatted correctly and something else is causing the original error. or 2) Some of the rows are formatted correctly and some are not. (Which I've seen happen before when I import an excel file to pandas..) Add try and except TypeError clauses so that the function returns date_to_convert without any formatting when there's a TypeError.

Comment: I got the following error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'datetime.time'